Why doesn't the Pinia store change in the Vue test?
I want to test the submitEvaluation function with vitest. I want to set the isDisabled to true using the disableSubmit function, but if I call the disableSubmit(true), the isDisabledSubmit still remains false, also it's initial value. I expect, that setLocked would not be called, because the isDisabledSubmit should be true, but as I mentioned, the isDisabled remains false after calling disableSubmit(true). I tried with wrapper.vm also imported useFormStore, but nothing helps. Can you tell me where the mistake is?
Here is the pinia stores:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useLockStore = defineStore("lockStore", {
    state: () => ({
        isLocked: false
    }),
    actions: {
        setIsLocked(value: boolean): void {
            this.isLocked = value;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getIsLocked(state): boolean {
            return state.isLocked;
        }
    }
});


import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useFormStore = defineStore("formStore", () => {
    const preventSubmit = ref(false);

    function disableSubmit(val: boolean): void {
        preventSubmit.value = val;
    }
    function isDisabledSubmit(): boolean {
        return preventSubmit.value;
    }

    return { disableSubmit, isDisabledSubmit: isDisabledSubmit() };
});


A part from a vue component, the function which I want to test, also I use composition api with setup in script tag.
const { disableSubmit, isDisabledSubmit } = useFormStore();
function submitEvaluation(): void {
    console.log(isDisabledSubmit);


    if (!isDisabledSubmit) {
        lockStore.setIsLocked(false);
        updateEvaluation(payload.value, closeDialog);
    }
}

defineExpose({
    lockStore,
    loadDropDown,
    resubmissionDate,
    onDropDownReady,
    isOpenDialog,
    openDialog,
    closeDialog,
    cancelDialog,
    resetDataFields,
    dataFields,
    updateEvaluation,
    submitEvaluation,
    isDisabledSubmit,
    disableSubmit
})

Part of the test file:
beforeEach(() => {
    // creates a fresh pinia and makes it active
    // so it's automatically picked up by any useStore() call
    // without having to pass it to it: `useStore(pinia)`
    setActivePinia(createPinia());
});

afterEach(() => {
    vi.clearAllMocks();
    vi.restoreAllMocks()
});


test.only('SubmitEvaluation_ifIsDisabledSubmitIsTrue_ExpectLockStoreSetLockedNotToBeCalled', async () => {
        const formStore = useFormStore();
        const lockStore = useLockStore();

        const spyOnFormStoreDisableSubmit = vi.fn(formStore.disableSubmit)
        formStore.disableSubmit = spyOnFormStoreDisableSubmit


        vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'submitEvaluation')
        // wrapper.vm.submitEvaluation = fnSubmitEvaluation

        vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'disableSubmit')
        // wrapper.vm.disableSubmit = fnDisableSubmit

        vi.spyOn(formStore, 'disableSubmit')

        // wrapper.vm.submitEvaluation()
        // // expect(wrapper.vm.disableSubmit).toBeCalledTimes(1)

        wrapper.vm.disableSubmit(true)
        wrapper.vm.isDisabledSubmit = vi.fn().mockReturnValue(true) as any
        console.log(wrapper.vm.isDisabledSubmit);

        formStore.disableSubmit(true)
        formStore.isDisabledSubmit = true
        wrapper.vm.isDisabledSubmit = vi.fn().mockReturnValue(true) as any
        wrapper.vm.submitEvaluation()
        // after the isDisabledSubmit is set to true, the setIsLocked should not be called
        expect(wrapper.vm.lockStore.setIsLocked).toBeCalledTimes(0)
        // expect(lockStore.setIsLocked).toBeCalledTimes(0)

    })


The test is unnecessarily convoluted, it's hard to follow what happens, some parts duplicate each other which may lead to unforeseen circumstances. There is no need to refer stores through wrapper.vm.
Mocking store functions from the outside can be unpredictable because this may interfere with Pinia internal mechanisms, especially with store functions. The main problem is that isDisabledSubmit is exposed as static value and loses reactivity at isDisabledSubmit: isDisabledSubmit(). And it's inconsistently used as a value and as a function through the test. It should be store getter (computed) and should be mocked by mocking preventSubmit state it relies on:
const isDisabledSubmit = computed(() => preventSubmit.value);

There is no need for isDisabledSubmit at all, preventSubmit state could be just exposed and accessed directly.
